# Analysis and Prediction using SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, etl

I have a transactional application on MSSQL database where people can send money to other people at anytime (More like Cashapp), i want to be able to predict a customer's frequent beneficiary on random days.

AIM: I want to be able to tell a customer on 27th of the month "Hey Mr. A, you mostly send money to Mr. B on the 27th of every month, do you want to do so today?"

How best can i achieve this using SQL?

Comment: Having your table(s) definition would be handy to know.